# In Node, delete all files older than an hour?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to delete any files older than an hour.  This is for automatically cleaning up a tmp uploads directory.

Here is my code:

```
fs.readdir( dirPath, function( err, files ) {
    if ( err ) return console.log( err );
    files.forEach(function( file ) {
        var filePath = dirPath + file;
        fs.stat( filePath, function( err, stat ) {
            if ( err ) return console.log( err );
            var livesUntil = new Date();
            livesUntil.setHours(livesUntil.getHours() - 1);
            if ( stat.ctime < livesUntil ) {
                fs.unlink( filePath, function( err ) {
                    if ( err ) return console.log( err );
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However this just deletes everything in the directory, regardless of whether or not it was uploaded over an hour ago.

Am I misunderstanding how to check the age of the file in Node?

Comment: have you tried using `.getTime()` on both `Date` objects like [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) suggests

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am using [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) to recursively delete any file/folder that is older than one hour.

According to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats), you should use [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on the ctime [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object instance in order to compare.

```
var uploadsDir = __dirname + '/uploads';

fs.readdir(uploadsDir, function(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file, index) {
    fs.stat(path.join(uploadsDir, file), function(err, stat) {
      var endTime, now;
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }
      now = new Date().getTime();
      endTime = new Date(stat.ctime).getTime() + 3600000;
      if (now > endTime) {
        return rimraf(path.join(uploadsDir, file), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
          console.log('successfully deleted');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 37):

I've used [find-remove](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-remove#delete-all-jpg-files-older-than-one-hour) for a similar usecase.

According to the documentation and what you are trying to do, the code will be:

```
var findRemoveSync = require('find-remove');
findRemoveSync(__dirname + '/uploads', {age: {seconds: 3600}});
```

I'm actually running that every 6 minutes and deleting files older than 1 hour by doing:

```
setInterval(findRemoveSync.bind(this,__dirname + '/uploads', {age: {seconds: 3600}}), 360000)
```

See [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/document-conversion-nodejs/blob/master/app.js) example on how I'm using find-remove to cleanup the `/uploads` folder.

Comment: Nitpicky, but in your setInterval example it will execute every 6 minutes (not every hour).

Comment: Every 6 minutes I'm calling the method to remove files that are older than 1 hour. So each file will live for up to 1 hour and 5 minutes and 59 seconds

Comment: Right - I'm saying you said "I'm actually running that every hour by doing:" but it's actually running every 6 minutes.

Comment: Sadly, find-remove is completely synchronous. Do not use in e.g. HTTP requests and with caution.

Comment: **_"as a precaution, nothing happens when there are no options."_** Maybe this was changed in later versions but you also need to specify another option, like `files: "*.*"`, in order for any files to get deleted.

Comment: More clean parammetes: `setInterval(findRemoveSync, 360000, __dirname + '/uploads', { age: { seconds: 3600 } })`

Answer (score 7):

Simple recursive solution only del all files !dirs run every 5 hours del older files that 1 day

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

setInterval(function() {
    walkDir('./tmpimages/', function(filePath) {
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stat) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = new Date(stat.mtime).getTime() + 86400000; // 1days in miliseconds

    if (err) { return console.error(err); }

    if (now > endTime) {
        //console.log('DEL:', filePath);
      return fs.unlink(filePath, function(err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
      });
    }
  })  
});
}, 18000000); // every 5 hours



function walkDir(dir, callback) {
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach( f => {
    let dirPath = path.join(dir, f);
    let isDirectory = fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
    isDirectory ? 
      walkDir(dirPath, callback) : callback(path.join(dir, f));
  });
};
```

[Source of function](https://medium.com/@allenhwkim/nodejs-walk-directory-f30a2d8f038f)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain Node script (for instance name it `cleanlogs.js`), tested on `v18.7.0` using the fs promises api (native module). You really dont need any fancy npm modules:

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import path from 'path';

/**
 * Remove all files in a directory older than the given number of seconds.
 * @param {String} directory The directory to look in.
 * @param {String[]} extensions The file extensions to match.
 * @param {Number} seconds The minimum number of seconds since the creation time of the file.
 */
(async (directory, extensions, seconds) => {
    const currentTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    const files = Array.from(await fs.readdir(directory)).filter((file) => {
        return extensions.indexOf(file.split('.').at(-1)) !== -1;
    });

    for (const file of files) {
        const filePath = path.join(directory, file);
        const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
        const birthTime = Math.floor(stats.birthtimeMs / 1000);
        if (currentTime - birthTime > seconds) {
            fs.rm(filePath);
        }
    }
})('./logs', ['log'], 60 * 60 * 12);
```

The example removes files in the `./logs` directory for any file with the `log` extension (e.g. `error.log`), older than 12 hours (`60 * 60 * 12` seconds).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're comparing whatever "stat.ctime" is to the entire Date object.

```
if ( stat.ctime < livesUntil ) {
```

Shouldn't it read:

```
if ( stat.ctime < livesUntil.getHours() ) {
```

Comment: stat.ctime is also a date object

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create my own function thanks to other response in this topic. It is a *typescript style* using like an Helper in a @NestJs project (used for ExceptionHandling here).

#### Dependencies

I'm also using

- [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) for definig date
- Node js [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package
- and [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

#### Parameter

- *parentDirectory* : the directory where the function will walk through and delete all files older than `60 hours`

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';

export default function walk(parentDirectory: string): void {
  let list;
  let i = 0;

  try {
    // store list of all file and directory in the current directory
    list = fs.readdirSync(parentDirectory);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.toString());
  }

  return (function next() {
    const file = list[i++];

    if (file) {
      const filePath = path.resolve(parentDirectory, file);
      const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

      if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
        // if it's a directory, continue walking
        walk(filePath);

        return next();
      } else {
        // see stats of the file for its creation date
        fs.stat(filePath, (err, stat) => {
          if (err) console.error(err);

          // using moment.js to compare expiration date
          const now = moment();
          const endTimeFile = moment(stat.ctimeMs).add(60, 'minutes');

          if (now > endTimeFile) {
            try {
              // delete file if expired
              fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
              console.log(`successfully deleted ${filePath}`);
            } catch (err) {
              throw new InternalServerErrorException(
                'file not deleted successfully',
              );
            }
          }
        });

        return next();
      }
    }
  })();
}
```

Comment: its amazing how bloated and dirty you can make a function for something so mundane...

Answer (score 1):

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

var uploadsDir = __dirname + '/Test';
let modifiedFiles = [];
var noOfFile = 2;

var files = fs.readdirSync(uploadsDir);
files.forEach((file, index) => {
    var stat = fs.statSync(path.join(uploadsDir, file));
    modifiedFiles.push({ cTime: stat.ctime.valueOf(), Name: file, Index: index });
    console.log(stat);
});

var data = modifiedFiles.sort((a, b) => b.cTime - a.cTime);
var MaxCTime = data[noOfFile - 1].cTime;
data.forEach((v) => {
    if (MaxCTime > v.cTime) {
        fs.unlink(path.join(uploadsDir, v.Name));
    }
});
console.log('older files deleted except last 2 modified');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.