# Delete file automatically after sometime from node server

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I am working on a file converter.
First, I get a file from the user and save it to the uploads folder of my node server and after conversion, I saved it to the download folder.
As the file gets converted I delete the uploaded file from the folder but using fs.unlink but and after 5000 ms of conversion I delete the file from the download folder but the problem is when at the same time more than 1 user uploads the file.

It isn't able to delete the file of the second user from the downloads folder, it shows an error message.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'downloads/1617962744875.yml'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'downloads/1617962744875.yml'
}
```

**Code:**

```
var path = require('path')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)) //Appending extension
    }
})

app.post("/upload", upload.array("files"), uploadFiles);

const uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {
    const file = await req.files[0];
    postmanCollection = file.path;
    outputFile = `downloads/${file.filename.slice(0, -5)}.yml`
    await convert();
    await fs.unlink(file.path, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error in deleting a file from uploads')
        } else {
            console.log('succesfully deleted from the uploads folder')
        }
    })
    res.json(file);
}

const convert = async () => {
    try {
        let result = // doing my conversion over here
        setTimeout(() => {
            fs.unlink(outputFile, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log('succesfully deleted from the downloads folder')
                }
            })
        }, 5000)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Anyone Please help me with this.

Comment: Please clarify by [edit]ing your question. It seems your failure occurs when two different users upload files with precisely the same name. Is that correct?

Comment: No, when two users upload a file at the same time. It only deletes the first downloaded file and then for the second user it again try to delete the first downloaded file(that is already deleted after 5 seconds). It isn't able to update the name of the second downloaded file for the second user doesn't get updated.
 Does it make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestions.

1. Give uploaded files unique names. Random text strings can be good. Don't rely on your users' choice of filenames to maintain uniqueness.
2. Take the unlink operations out of your upload and conversion processing. Instead, make a pass over your directories once every few minutes to delete files that have reached a certain age. Here's a [good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167297/in-node-delete-all-files-older-than-an-hour) on how to do that.