# rimraf Error: invalid rimraf options. Unable to delete files automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I have an issue of multer depositing some files after it has been uploaded to cloudinay. I then found a post [In Node, delete all files older than an hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167297/in-node-delete-all-files-older-than-an-hour) that introduced me to rimraf. I have not been able to implement it and this is the error I have from the console

[image: Screenshot of terminal with error]

Please have a look at the code, the error is line 16 from the stack trace which is => `return rimraf(path.join(uploadsDir, file), function (err)`

```
const rimraf = require("rimraf");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

var uploadsDir = path.normalize(__dirname + "/public/images");
fs.readdir(uploadsDir, function (err, files) {
  files.forEach(function (file, index) {
    fs.stat(path.join(uploadsDir, file), function (err, stat) {
      var endTime, now;
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }
      now = new Date().getTime();
      endTime = new Date(stat.ctime).getTime() + 3600000;
      if (now > endTime) {
        return rimraf(path.join(uploadsDir, file), function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
          console.log("successfully deleted");
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I am quiet amazed because I can't find the issue and not one has reported my experience. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation, it seems the second parameter( if you are using version 4) that should be passed to the function is the options object, while you are passing a function, check this [URL](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf#rimraff-opts---promise)

Comment: Please are you saying the function passed as a second argument should not be there and I should rather pass the options object or to leave it black to apply defaults

Comment: whatever works for you, if you don't need to change the options I think you can remove the second paramater

Comment: OK so the server is not crushing but nothing happens. The files are just seated there. They did not give much information how the promise works so I did this `return rimraf(path.join(uploadsDir, file)).then((file) =>resolve(file)`

Comment: look the documentation here https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf#rimraff-opts---promise, it returns a promise so using try and catch with await you can see the output of the function and if it's succeeded or there's an error